# Android Studio custom template with build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, freemarker

I have created template for Android Studio to simplify creating new project. Everything worked ok with Android Studio 3.0.1. After updating to 3.1 and 3.1.1 I noticed problem with merging build.gradle file.

My build.gradle.ftl looks like this: https://gist.github.com/masztalski/89db6656a9b22e1f5e307030b19ae042

In recipe.xml.ftl line for merging is
    `<merge from="root/build.gradle.ftl"
             to="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/build.gradle" />`

This is the same as other templates avaible in folder. Yet with AS 3.0.1 I had problem with ordering of blocks in build.gradle, but I fixed it with adding to `Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\build.gradle.ftl` block `ext{}` and than everything worked OK

Does anyone has idea how to properly configure template for build.gradle file?